# SQL join on columns of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have this table (top row is column names):

```
security    quote_type      price
sec_1       bid             3.4
sec_1       ask             3.6
sec_2       bid             5.2
sec_2       ask             5.4
sec_3       bid             2.3
sec_4       ask             7.8
```

Need a query to achieve these results:

```
security    bid     ask
sec_1       3.4     3.6
sec_2       5.2     5.4
sec_3       2.3     null
sec_4       null    7.8
```

Using SQL Server.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What if there will be more than 1 bid per security?

Comment: For just one pair of `bid`, `ask` per security you can use *conditional aggregation* to get the expected result. You can find plenty of similar cases here in SO.

Comment: There will be at most one bid and one ask per security

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just use conditional aggregation or `pivot`:

```
select security,
       max(case when quote_type = 'bid' then price end) as bid,
       max(case when quote_type = 'ask' then price end) as ask
from t
group by security;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join between two queries on the table:

```
SELECT          a.security, bid, ask
FROM            (SELECT security, price AS bid
                 FROM   mytable
                 WHERE  quote_type = 'bid') a
FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT security, price AS ask
                 FROM   mytable
                 WHERE  quote_type = 'ask') b ON a.security = b.security
```